# Apple Counter Widget with api/dakboard implementation

Tags: ios, api, widget, counter

i would like to build a iOS widget with which I can trigger a counter on a website. Like I press the widget and the counter on the website rises by one. Is there any way to do this? API/any kind of widget would also work.
Thanks ;)

Comment: Hello, You should find informations into the apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/widgetkit/

Comment: I’m sorry but I have no idea how to do thislike the hole process

Comment: Theses informations are available into the documentation, the life cycle, creation, etc of a widget is well explained, but a bit tricky I agree